# Login with Active Directory and C#?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm working on a Windows Forms application. I have a login for users, but I want to be able to login with the credentials of the company.

How can I do this, is it by using Active Directory?

If there is any other way, please tell me or leave me an example please

Comment: You can check this resource https://auth0.com/blog/using-ldap-with-c-sharp/

Comment: You say "with the credentials of the company" - what credentials? For what system or infrastructure? Answer that, and you know your answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LogonUser win32 API as shown below.

In below example, the credentials are hardcoded.

Instead of hardcoding, you can accept those using the UI and call the isValidCredentials method on Login button click.

```
public class Program
{

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    public static extern bool LogonUser(string userName, string domainName, string password, int LogonType, int LogonProvider,ref IntPtr phToken);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program obj = new Program();
        bool isValid = obj.IsValidateCredentials("myUserName","MyPassword","MyDomain");
        Console.WriteLine(isValid == true ? "Valid User details" : "Invalid User Details");
        Console.Read();
        //// instead of console.readline and writeline, open your protected form.
    }

    public bool IsValidateCredentials(string userName, string password, string domain)
    {
        IntPtr tokenHandler = IntPtr.Zero;
        bool isValid = LogonUser(userName, domain, password, 2, 0, ref tokenHandler);
        return isValid;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.